# why use InverseProperty attribute in this scenario?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was reading a textbook that provides an example to use `InverseProperty` attribute.
Two tables in the database are "Shoes" and "Colors"
 corresponding classes are `Shoe` and `Style`

```
public class Shoe
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Column("ColorId")]
    public long StyleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StyleId")]
    public Style Style { get; set; }
}

[Table("Colors")]
public class Style
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public long UniqueIdent { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string StyleName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Shoe> Shoes { get; set; }
}
```

and the author says that if we want to name the navigation property on the `Style` class with a different name "Products", then we need to add InverseProperty arrtibute as:

```
public class Style
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public long UniqueIdent { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string StyleName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Shoe.Style))]
    public IEnumerable<Shoe> Products { get; set; }
}
```

so my questions are:

Q1- isn't that there is no restriction on naming Collection navigation property such as `IEnumerable<Shoe>` in this example? we can name it whatever we want as `public IEnumerable<Shoe> XXX{ get; set; }` where XXX could be any legal property name? or EF still enforce a rule that the property name for Collection navigation property has to be the type in the collection(`Shoe` in this example) and then append a `s` char? (`Shoe` + `s` is `Shoes`)

Q2-isn't that `InverseProperty` attribute be used when **there is more than one pair of navigation properties between two entity types**? we only have one pair here, so why still need to use `InverseProperty`?

Comment: There is no reason i can see to use it

Comment: @TheGeneral  could you also check this post to see if there is also no reason to use `no-build` when scaffolding existing database   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526519/no-build-prevents-the-scaffolding-process-from-being-performed

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do here, is just try these things. if it works yehaa, if it doesnt well you also have an answer. We call it empirical evidence

Comment: @TheGeneral I have tried that,  the propblem I have for 'no-build` is, if 'no-build` is needed(because it exists,), that means I fundamentally misunderstand the process of scaffolding.are you familiar woth `no-build`?